# Spring MVC AngularJS - Post Redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I believe I am just missing something obvious.

I have a post that works but it gives me HTML as response. Normally that would be great if I was actually trying to load some more information on the current page. But I really want it to redirect.

**The post in MainService.js**

```
searchOpportunities : function(title, location) {
                                return $http
                                        .post(
                                                '/',
                                                $.param({
                                                    title : title,
                                                    location : location
                                                }),
                                                {
                                                    headers : {
                                                        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                                    }
                                                })
                            }
```

**The response**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView search_Post(@RequestParam(value = "title", required = true) String title, @RequestParam(value = "location", required = true) String location) {
        ModelAndView searchView = new ModelAndView("search");
        searchView.addObject("searchTitle", title);
        searchView.addObject("searchLocation", location);
        return searchView;
    }
```

To clarify:

I want the page to change to the searchView after the post is sent. Right now it's just sending HTML as response... but I want redirect with the right objects "searchTitle" and "searchLocation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're just *rendering* the `searchView` view after `POST`, not *redirecting* to somewhere. If you really want to `Redirect`, use `redirect:` prefix. Suppose you have a `/search` endpoint and gonna redirect to it after successful `POST` on `/`, then:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search_Post(@RequestParam(value = "title", required = true) String title, @RequestParam(value = "location", required = true) String location) {
    ...
    return "redirect:/search";
}
```

You could render your `searchView` in `/search` endpoint, if you want to. Read more about Redirect Views [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix).

Comment: "redirect:search" won't keep my objects in the view when the view loads. Also at the moment redirect:search is giving me a 302 found with no redirect. RedirectView requires the url to be formatted as a URL encoded format, search?title=this&location=that I don't want to make it to accept that type of submission. All I want is if post happens load search.jsp with Objects searchTitle as this string and searchLocation as this string with no changes in main url to the user the URL would be www.mysite.com/search

Comment: If want to pass model attributes between redirects, use `RedirectAttributes`.

Comment: By default it appends model attributes as query strings

Comment: And create a controller method that handles the `/search` endpoint. If you do not create that, you would get a `Not Found`, of course.